# Integrate various properties in fn function

Tags: jquery, properties, prototype, transition

I created the following function (to use with Rico StCruz genious jquery-transit plugIn):

```
$.fn.translateLeftTop = function( left, top, duration, easing ) {
    var $this  = $(this);
    var currentLeftPx = parseInt( $this.css('left') );
    var currentTopPx = parseInt( $this.css('top') );
    var parentWidth = $this.parent().width();
    var parentHeight = $this.parent().height();
    // final left layout destination in px
    var finalLeftPx = parentWidth/100 * left; 
    var finalTopPx = parentHeight/100 * top;
    // actual distances to final left/top layout destination in px
    var distanceLeftPx = currentLeftPx - finalLeftPx;
    var distanceTopPx = currentTopPx - finalTopPx;

    $this.transition( { x: -distanceLeftPx, y: -distanceTopPx }, duration, easing, function() {
        $this.stop(true).css( { left: left +'%', top: top +'%', x: 0, y: 0 } );
    } ); 
}
```

I would instead love to use it as following:

```
$("#element").translateLeftTop( { left: '5%', top: '5%' }, 500, 'easeOutSine' )
```

and keep it open wether both values or only one by the code, so that also

```
 $("#element").translateLeftTop( { left: '5%' }, 500, 'easeOutSine' )
```

or

```
 $("#element").translateLeftTop( { top: '5%' }, 500, 'easeOutSine' )
```

would be usable.

Answer (score 0):

Your function takes 3 parameters, not 4 with how you have outlined it.

You currently have `function( left, top, duration, easing ){...` but you instead want to have `function( options, duration, easing )` where `options` is an object.

You can then access properties `top`, `left` or anything else you want from the `options` object. You will want to check that the property exists before using it however. For example, to check if the `top` property exists before using it in a function, you can do:

```
if (options.hasOwnProperty('top')) {
    // do something with options.top
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I thought about that, too. But in this case I would have to do 3 complete versions of the last code part ($this.transition…), one with 2 option properties, one with only the first and one with only the second. I am afraid this would become a horrible piece of code. :-(

Does someone know how f.e. jquery solves this kind of function, for example with their .animate() function. I cannot imagine that there are endless if else cases in their, because animate() takes a whole lot more parameters and providing in this way all combinations would be almost impossible. Do you know what I mean?